# Qual o erro no meu código JS (laços repetição) que não está correto e se perde quando o usuário digita 31

Tags: javascript, lógica

```
<script>

            // ver porquê será que se o usuário digitar 31 ele não apresenta nada 
            // só dá a mensagem após o 32

    
        for ( var i = window.prompt(`digite um valor entre 0 e 30: `) ; i <= 30 ; i++) {

            document.write(`Lista de números até o 30 :  ${i} <br>`)



                 } if (i >= 31) {
                    
                    document.write(`numero digitado ${i} acima de 30`)

            }


</script>
```

Comment: `i` está recebendo uma _string_ e não _number_. Faça a conversão de tipos.

Comment: O `for` sempre testa a condição antes de executar o bloco. Ou seja, se digitar 31, a condição `i <= 30` é falsa e ele sai do `for` (não executa mais o que está dentro dele)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você misturou um for com if de uma forma estranha.
Separe as coisas deixe seu cod mais levigel.

```
    <script>
    
    while(true){
        var i = window.prompt('digite um valor entre 0 e 30: ');
        if(i<=30){
            document.write('Lista de números até o 30 :  '+i+' <br>');
        } else {
            document.write('numero digitado '+i+' acima de 30');
            break;
        }
    
}   
    
    </script>
```

so que desta forma ele so vai parar o `while` quando for digitado algum numero maior que o 30. por tanto so vai exibir na tela quando isto acontecer.

segue o link do fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dkc3vfxL/

segue update:

```js
var maxValue=30;
var i = window.prompt('digite um valor entre 0 e 30: ');
if(i<=maxValue){
    document.write('Lista de números até o 30 : ');
    for(u=i;u<=maxValue;u++){
       document.write(''+u+' ');
    }
} else {
    document.write('numero digitado '+i+' acima de 30');
}
```

Comment: o objetivo do programa é que se o usuário digitar por exemplo 27 o sistema irá listar na tela 27,28,29,30  mais queria deixar a possibilidade do usuário digitar 31 e dai o sistema dizer que 31 é maior que 30 e portanto não válido

Comment: vou postar o update

Comment: grande ajuda , obrigado

Comment: se resolveu flaga como resolvido ^^

Comment: agradeço imensamente a ajuda

Comment: como marco como resolvido amigo ?

Comment: se ajudou tem uma setinha pra cima vc clica nela e se resolveu vc marca no simbolo de check ou lado da postagem.